# Survey Monkey editing likert scale

Tags: surveymonkey

I am currently working on my dissertation, and as part of it i have constructed a questionnaire on Survey Monkey.

In one of the questions, a matrix type, with ten items, with four choices, i made a miscalculation. I graded the scale from 1-4 instead of 0-3 and i already have about 14 answers to it. Now, if i edit the questionnaire and recode the scale from 0-3 how is that going to affect the answers i already have?

Are they going to change automatically to conform to the new scale, or is it going to disrupt my whole questionnaire?

Answer (score 0):

You can change it and it won't affect your responses. The weight you set on a choice is used during the analytics stage and not actually stored with the response.

The [help docs](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Matrix-Question) don't say so explicitly but seems to suggest it's safe. In the Analyzing Results section:

> If needed, you can change the weight of each answer choice in the
>   Design section of the survey, even after the survey has collected
>   responses.